# Looping through webelements with selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently trying to automate a process using Selenium with python, but I have hit a roadblock with it. The list is part of a list which is under a tree. I have identified the base of the tree with the following xpath

`item = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='filter']/ul/li[1]//ul//li")`

`items = item.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")`

I am trying to Loop through the "items" section but need and click on anything with an "input" tag

`for k in items:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((k.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input")))).click()`

When execute the above I get the following error:
"TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement"

For some reason .click() will not work if I use something like the below.
`k.find_element_by_tag_name("input").click()`
it only works if i use the webdriverwait. I have had to use the web driver wait method anytime i needed to click something on the page.

My question is:
What is the syntax to replicate `items = item.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")`
for `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((k.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input")))).click()`
i.e how do I use a base path and append to the using the private methods `find_elements(By.TAG_NAME)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a work around and get Selenium to do what i need. 
I had to call the  javascript execution, so instead of trying to get
`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((k.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input")))).click()`  to work, i just used
`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", k.find_element_by_tag_name("input"))`

Its doing exactly what I needed it to do.